# Android widget remoteviews null value in onReceive

Tags: android, android-widget

I am new to android programming and I am trying to figure this out for hours, but still can't get it to work. I am creating a widget that has 2 buttons. One button works fine (button that calls out an activity) but another button that's suppose to change picture (like a togglekey) doesn't work. I get a `NullPointerException`. I have traced the problem and it seems like remoteViews is null when it is passed on to onReceive

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
boolean status = false;
private RemoteViews remoteViews;
Button bMain;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    final int n = appWidgetIds.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        final int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
        configIntent.setAction("callingActivity");
        PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, configIntent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bWidgetMain,
                configPendingIntent);

        configIntent = new Intent(context, Widget.class);
        configIntent.setAction("callingibFlash");
        configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                configIntent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ibFlash, configPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    }

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("callingActivity")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Main", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("callingibFlash")) {
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.ibFlash,
                R.drawable.flashlight_on);
    } else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend having `remoteViews` as a local variable instead of holding a reference as an instance variable. You can get a new reference in your `onReceive()` implementation through the `Context` and use the `AppWidgetManager` to update your widget as you did in `onUpdate()`.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    if (intent.getAction().equals("callingActivity")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Main", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("callingibFlash")) {
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
        myRefactoredUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        // use for loop as in onUpdate to get to your remoteViews
        final int n = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            final int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.ibFlash, R.drawable.flashlight_on);
        }
    } else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

Once you have the new RemoteViews can call setImageViewResource() and whatever else you want. It might be also better to call super.onReceive for every case.

Comment: it was problem with updating on onReceive

Comment: @NanoControl: Yes, that's how I understood it as well. Did the answer help? Or do you have further questions? To clarify, you can have a similar for loop over the `appWidgetIds` to get to your `RemoteViews`, similar as in your `onUpdate`.

Comment: OK, I added a more concrete code example based on your original code. Hope that clears things up.